# jQuery Slide in on click, slideOut on click with addclass not working?

Tags: jquery, onclick, slide, addclass, removeclass

I am attempting to make a slide out menu which has a button to slide in/out classed 'open'.

When the open button is clicked jQuery does the slide in and adds the class 'close' and removes class 'open' - this works fine.

Then when 'close' is clicked I am attempting to slide out, add class 'open' and remove class 'close' to take it back to it's original state.

But the close does not work, it adds the close class but the close function is not working on click, maybe you can't have a function on class that has been added...?

Any help much appreciated.

```
            $(".open").click(function(){
                $('.mainmenu').stop().animate({left: '0'}, 800);
                $( ".open" ).addClass( "close" );
                $( ".open" ).removeClass( "open" );
            });

            $(".close").click(function(){
                $('.mainmenu').stop().animate({left: '-180'}, 800);
                $( ".close" ).addClass( "open" );
                $( ".close" ).removeClass( "close" );
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your button has the "open" class at the beginning. Your javascript code will add the callback for the "open" class, and will do nothing for "close" class because there's no component with such class yet. A work around is to do the following:

```
function open() {
    $('.mainmenu').stop().animate({left: '0'}, 800);
    $( ".open" ).addClass( "close" );
    $( ".open" ).removeClass( "open" );
    $(".close").click(function(){
        close();
    });
}

function close() {
    $('.mainmenu').stop().animate({left: '-180'}, 800);
    $( ".close" ).addClass( "open" );
    $( ".close" ).removeClass( "close" );
    $(".open").click(function(){
        open();
    });
}

$(".open").click(function(){
    open();
});

$(".close").click(function(){
    close();
});
```

Comment: So if I use addClass and want to perform a function on that added class then the function must be within the function which has added the class?

Comment: It's about adding a handler to something that exist. "close" class is not present in the document when you are in a state having "open" button. So binding a callback to "close" class will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("body").on('click','.open', function(){
                $('.mainmenu').stop().animate({left: '0'}, 800);
      $( ".open" ).removeClass( "open" ).addClass( "close" );


            });


            $("body").on("click",".close", function(){
                $('.mainmenu').stop().animate({left: '-180'}, 800);
                $( ".close" ).addClass( "open" ).removeClass( "close" );

            });
```

Easier way, by using of on() method, for elements that aren't present on page load... Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urjsw5z1/2/